# Unable to drag and drop the images from scroll bar

Tags: html

Here is the 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesrod9000/p75ep4hs/)

In the above fiddle I could drag and drop items onto the wooden plate

```
<div id="scroll-pane" style="width:250px; height:100px; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;">
<table>
<tr><td>item 0</td></tr>
<tr><td>item 99</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

But I have added a scroll bar and Now I could not drag and drop onto the wooden plate

Scroll Bar [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesrod9000/r2fLvd1y/)

Comment: Please seperate you html/css/js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a new div 'scroll-pane' it works if we set the style to the div 'boxB'

```
<div id="boxB" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" ondrop="return dragDrop1(event)"
                    ondragover="return dragOver(event)" class='box' style="width: 250px; height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;">
.....
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/baga143/7xa5sbfg/)